# add item direction in tileList component

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, tilelist, right-to-left

I have Flash AS3 Project with tile list.
I have buttons on stage. each of them when clicked adds tile with a picture on it to the tileList using the addTile() function.
I'm using 2 columns in the tile list and I want the new tiles will appear from right to left (1st item - right column, 2nd item - left column..).
is it possible?
additionally, is it possible that each new item will be added to the top of the tileList instead of the bottom of it?

thank!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure weather this help you or not, But you can try **layoutDirection = rtl** property. this will change the direction of the tiles form right to left.

Comment: thanks. but it looks like it works only with flex and i'm working with flash.